# More than 26 appendices

Tags: numbering, appendices

For my thesis I have a document that contains more than 26 appendices. The appendices 1 up to 26 are are alphabetical numbered as A up to Z. However at the 27th appendix I get an error (although I though that LaTeX would automatically number the 27th appendix as AA):

`! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...

                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.1133 ...{Elaborated interview team leader}
                                                  \label{appendixaa}
?`

At line 1133 starts the 27th appendix. I was looking for the content of a generic error but are not getting anything wiser. I use sections in my appendix, because my documentclass is `article` which is more controlable in layout in my opinion:

```
\section{Elaborated interview team leader}\label{appendixaa}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE 24/09/2013**

I have done what Erreg suggested, but now the message is that `appendix.tex could not be found`:

My mainfile (thesis.tex):

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{appendix}
    \usepackage{alphalph}

\renewcommand\thesection{\AlphAlph{\value{section}}}

    \include{Sections/appendix}

    \end{document}
```

In the map Sections, `appendix.tex` is the file with all appendices:

```
\appendix
\input{appendix}

\section{ appendix a}\label{appendixa}
\pb

\section{appendix b}\label{appendixb}
\pb

\setcounter{section}{25}

\section{appendix z}\label{appendixz}
\pb

\section{appendix aa}\label{apendixaa}
\pb

\section{appendix ab}\label{apendixab}
\pb

\section{appendix ac}\label{apendixac}
\pb
```

***UPDATE:03/10/2013***
This is what i have now:
thesis.text  (main file):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%Enabled packages
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\include{Sections/appendix}

\end{document}
```

appendix.text (in the subfolder Sections):

```
\appendix

\setcounter{section}{24} % just to see the effect

\section{Twenty five}

\section{Twenty six}

\section{Twenty seven}
```

The error I get now is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.33 \section{Twenty seven}
```

Above example is the same as Ergg provided. Any idea? I do not see the light anymore.

Comment: The directory structure to `appendix.tex` must have changed. You either moved the source, or you've moved `appendix.tex` to a different location (not in the immediate subfolder `Sections`).

Comment: @Werner: That was also my first opinion but the subfolder contains the file appendix.text. Furthermore the name of the subfolder matches the name of the subfolder I mentioned in thesis.tex

Comment: Could someone help me with this situation?

Comment: Here's what seems to be the problem: In your main document you include `appendix` (`\include{Sections/appendix}`). This should include `appendix.tex` in the `Sections` subfolder. Then, inside that file you use `\input{appendix}`, which should do something *very* similar. This seems like a circular reference. *Remove `\input{appendix}`*.

Comment: @Werner: The solution you provide results in other errors which I have posted at the Update of 03/10/2013.

Comment: In your update your forgot to set `\renewcommand\thesection{\AlphAlph{\value{section}}}` around `\appendix`. So, even though `\appendix` switches the display of sections to alphabetic, you'll still run out of numbers after 26. Adding back the [`alphalph` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/alphalph) and using it to reset the counter display for `section` should fix it.

Comment: @Werner: it worked but now the prefix `'Appendix'` is not showed anymore but instead `'A Title'` thus the letter of the appendix and not the word appendix. How can that be fixed? Furthermore the output of appendices after 26 is, for example the 27th appendix, `'AATitle'` without the space between AA and Title and the prefix Appendix (I want `Appendix AA Title`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a package also for this, called `alphalph`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{alphalph,etoolbox}
\appto\appendix{% patch \appendix so \AlphAlph is used
  \renewcommand\thechapter{\AlphAlph{\value{chapter}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\setcounter{chapter}{24} % just to see the effect

\chapter{Twenty five}

\chapter{Twenty six}

\chapter{Twenty seven}

\end{document}
```

Rather than the output, I'll show the relevant part of the terminal output:

```
Appendix Y.
[1][2]
Appendix Z.
[3] [4]
Appendix AA.
```

This assumes that the documentclass has chapters; if your document class is `article` or a similar one which has sections at the top level, use

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\AlphAlph{\value{section}}}
```

as the text of the patch.

Comment: I still get the same error. In my mainfile I declared the package and its command (with section in stead of chapter). I use an `\include{appendix}` to add the appendix to my article. Do I have to change something in the appendix file itself also?

Comment: @drs.Ekingen Can you add a scheme of the `appendix.tex` file contents? A test I made shows no problem.

Comment: `appendix.text` can be found here: [link](http://www.mijnbestand.nl/Bestand-7SCUCSRQODMO.tex)

Comment: @drs.Ekingen Why are you using `\begin{appendices}`? Of course this couldn't be foreseen. I believe that issuing `\appendix` and then `\input{appendix}` *without* the `appendices` environment is the best thing.

Comment: I do get the same error :( Is there an other solution that might work? Maybe forcing the numbering with an algorithmic code?

Comment: @drs.Ekingen Without a minimal example it's impossible to say.

Comment: Here is linked `thesis.tex`: [link](http://www.mijnbestand.nl/Bestand-E7QEPMOS4EOV.tex) and `appendix.tex`: [link](http://www.mijnbestand.nl/Bestand-HXR4EX8C4FYS.tex). To generate a PDF you must compile `thesis.tex`(main file). I have a small example in those files of what it should be.

Comment: @drs.Ekingen No link

Comment: The links are refering to the right file. But for convenience here again the links:

`thesis.text`: [link](http://www.mijnbestand.nl/Bestand-KUZW8BSU3PLD.tex)
`appendix.text`: [link](http://www.mijnbestand.nl/Bestand-XOIUALST3BSC.tex)

Comment: @drs.Ekingen If I add the suggested patch I don't get any error.

Comment: I do have now in `appendix.tex` `\appendix` followed by `\input{appendix}` but than I get the error: `file appendix.tex not found`... Or do I have to put it somewhere else?

Comment: @drs.Ekingen In your original document it's called differently: you should select the *right* name.

Comment: I changed in `thesis.tex` `\include{Sections/Appendix}` in `\include{Sections/appendix}` but get the same error.